# Embed Prezi in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'd like to get tips on how to embed Prezi like transitions in a PowerPoint presentation.

Specifically, is there a way to create an animation that zooms out of one slide into another? Is there a way for diagonal slide push animation? A way to put rotate text and rotate to it with animation?

I'm trying pptplex now, but looking for "native" PowerPoint solutions (add-ons are good also)

Comment: pptFlex is the only way to go. It doesn't have all of Prezi's options but it greatly expands what you can do.

Answer (score 1):

The big difference between a "Prezi-style" presentation and a "PowerPoint-style" presentation is that Prezi puts the whole presentation onto one big canvas, whereas PowerPoint distributes the content between different slides. So the "secret" of creating a "Prezi-style" presentation in PowerPoint is to put everything onto one slide. 
This might sound a bit crazy, but [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsPzQV9Hf0o&index=2&list=PL-uHoQ-eXZggtO8Ii_wnCV2LlOUXL7j8E) explains the process very well. 
It will probably get too complex if you try to convert a 50-slide PowerPoint Presentation to "Prezi-style", but for a limited number of slides you can actually duplicate it, nicely.

Comment: Very interesting concept!  You can take it a step farther by having only two "views' per side and then seamlessly transitioning to a new slide with the same content.  In this matter, you get the benefits of the prezi style with much bigger content.